# Problems displaying JSON data with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Trying to figure out why values in a key value pair of an object show as undefined when being displayed in HTML.
The JSON code is as followed:

```
{"products" : [
    {
      "name" : "-------",
      "id" : " --------",
      "price" : "---------",
      "description" : "--------"
    },
    {
      "name" : "-------",
      "id" : " --------",
      "price" : "---------",
      "description" : "--------"
    }
]}
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="speakerbox">
  <h1>title</h1>
  <div id="object"></div>
</div>
```

js code:

```
$.getJSON( 'products.json', function (products) {
    console.log(products);
    var output = '<ul>';
    $.each(products, function (key, val) {
         output += '<li>' + val.id + '</li>';
    });
    output += '</ul>';
    $('#object').html(output);
});
```

If I use the console.log() method I can see the objects when I debug in chrome however instead of seeing the value, in its place in HTML it outputs "undefined". When i run the js through an online validator it tells me the following: 
'$' was used before it was defined for these code pieces

```
$.getJSON( 'products.json', function (products) 
$.each(products, function (key, val) 
$('#object').html(output)
```

Is there a problem with my function calls? New to JSON so not sure why its doing this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`products` will contain an object that looks like this:

```
{"products" : [ ... ]}
```

The variable you've called `products` is and object. It contains a property also called `products` which has a value that is an array. To access it you need `products.products`.

To iterate over it, you need `$.each(products.products` in place of `$.each(products`.

For this reason, it's probably better to call your variable `response`. It makes much  more sense to say `response.products` than `products.products`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm having difficulty understanding the difference between the products object and products property and where the difference lies within the code. I'm under the impression that I'm naming an object "products" that contains an array of objects with different key value pairs. Is the "products" property defined in the js?

Comment: After further review I can traverse the logic now. Thank you for your response.